# What is the word for someone who helps you finish a sentence (but in a good way)?

Tags: single-word-requests, compliment

You know that feeling when you’re about to finish a particular thought and suddenly someone else, a friend or a stranger, finishes your sentence better than you possibly could have? Is there a word for that in English, or in any language?

Comment: I don't know of a particular word for "*friendly sentence finisher*"  but *kindred spirit* may sum up your feelings about that person if they always feel the same way you do about things.

Comment: This is a pretty interesting question, but I'm afraid there may be no single-word answer.

Comment: He's a smartass.

Comment: Jinx! You owe me a Coke

Answer (score 3):

When that happens, it is common to say ***"you took the words right out of my mouth"*** or ***"you read my mind"***

Comment: Or *I was about to say that* and then a self-conscious look that makes it clear the original idea was much less witty.

Answer (score 2):

I think the word you're looking for is **co-narration**.

I'm currently taking a communications class, and that is the word used when people who are in  a relationship (close or otherwise) finish each other's sentences because they have enough knowledge to infer what the person is trying to say.

Answer (score 1):

In any language? In France we call that person "sauveur" (=[lifesaver](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lifesaver)).

Answer (score 1):

Since an already existing answer seems unlikely, may I humbly suggest the term **clauseguard**?

Answer (score 0):

Dude.

However consider adding an adjective.

E.g. Awesome dude.

Comment: Did you pick your username before or after you decided to write this answer? :-)

Answer (score 0):

So, 
A "***life saver***" is often used to address someone who's been such a great help for you, including finishing things *better than you could possibly have*.

Answer (score -1):

Someone who brings the wrong kind of closure could be called a *terminator.*